# In django, how to redirect the website to the url of higher layer

Tags: django, redirect

How should i write the url so that it can direct me to previous layer? 
For example, we know that in view function, if currently we are at `www.example.com/users`, `HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')` would redirect us to `www.example.com/users/thanks/` instead of `www.example.com/thanks/`. How can have it redirect to to `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a leading `/`.  If you are at `www.example.com/users` and you return `HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')` the client will go to `www.example.com/users/thanks/`, but if you return `HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')` then the client will go to `www.example.com/thanks/`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Django's namespaced URL capabilities: e.g. `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thanks'))`, which in this example references a defined URL named `thanks`.

See [Django's URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#examples) for more details.